# Unload a flipview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to fully UNLOAD the flipview don't ask me why but i NEED to. i have tried `[super release];` and it didnt work below is my back button and then the did finish. Please help me to unload the view.

on the first view which gets activated once the flipview has finished.

```
- (void)flipViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipViewController *)controller 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

on the flip view which is a button that hides the flip view just hides doesn't unload

```
- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   [myFlipViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```